# webworks blackberry 10 window.open twitter facebook

Tags: twitter-oauth, blackberry-webworks, facebook-oauth, blackberry-10

i am just trying to implement facebook and twitter in my Webworks App and cannot get them work together.

I am using the FaceBook-OAuth-2 and the Twitter-OAuth-1 sample and i just put both stuff together and my problem is that only the first startOAuth() opens a window in the app to login the second doesn't so if i first clicked facebook it works after when i try twitter nothing happens.
https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples
thanks

```
function setClickHandlers() {
console.log('set click handlers');
var fb = document.getElementById('facebookOn');
fb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    // if the childWindow is already open, don't allow user to click the button
    if(childWindow !== null) {
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    toast('Contacting Facebook...');
    setTimeout(function() {
        startOAuth();
    }, 500);
});

console.log('set twitter click handlers');
var tw = document.getElementById('twitterOn');
tw.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    // if the childWindow is already open, don't allow user to click the button
    if(childWindow !== null) {
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    toast('Fetching access token...');
    setTimeout(function() {
        twittergetAccessToken();

    }, 500);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would start by adding some debug code in your click handler to see if that's getting called when you click the button in the first place.

If it is, then I recommended you use Web Inspector (console) to see if there are any errors.  If there are, they'll show up there.

Good reference for Web Inspector here - http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/web_inspector_overview_1553586_11.html

If the click handler is not being fired then perhaps you have the wrong element ID,  or the setClickHandlers function is not being executed.